LibGdx projects are failing to build in Android Studio - what is going wrong and how do I fix it?
I used the project generation tool on LibGdx's website (here: https://libgdx.com/wiki/start/project-generation) to generate a template project (as per their official documentation. I set the project to use the Android SDK installed alongside Android Studio (under C:\Users\<myuserdirectory>\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk). I imported the project into Android Studio, and clicked the run button.
The build failed and the following errors were displayed:

I have little to no familiarity with debugging gradle issues, so I was wondering what exactly is going wrong, and how do I fix it?

You have to post full trace to help us understand your problem.
Maybe Android Studio/File->Invalidate Cache could help?
Libgdx Litoff generated sample project should run without any problem "from the box". Just checked it yesterday.
